# Python dependencies issues

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, python, dpkg

I am using ubutu 14.04.
I am getting the following error when I run certbot-auto from letsencrypt.com (althoug i don't think thats relevant), and get the following error message:

```
python-dev : Depends: python (= 2.7.5-5ubuntu3) but 2.7.12-1 is to be installed
python-virtualenv : Depends: python-pkg-resources but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: python-setuptools but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I try to install these pakcages manually I get errors such as `dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/path/to/Python-2.7.12': Directory not empty`
My current version of python is 2.7.6... Is it a good idea for me to just completely uninstall 2.7.6 and install 2.7.5 instead?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? What is the output of `apt-cache policy python python-dev`?

Comment: You are correct - you should downgrade back to the version of Python that your release of Ubuntu is designed for. Changing the system python is one easy way to break your system terribly.